# getting the id from a foreignkey relationship django

Tags: python, django

I want to get the id or pk of a ForeignKey relationship **post_comment** but I've tried many different ways to catch it and i do not have any good result, please guys give me a hand in this situation

> In *views.py*

```
class createComment(View):
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "createComment.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        obj = self.form_class(None)
        obj.title_comment = self.request.POST['title_comment']
        obj.body_comment = self.request.POST['body_comment']
        obj.post_comment = self.pk
        obj.save()
```

> In *models.py*

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user_comment = models.ForeignKey("auth.User")
    title_comment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body_comment = models.TextField()
    timestamp_comment = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post_comment = models.ForeignKey("Post", null=True)
    status_comment = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title_comment)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_comment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a primary key in the url, and then use it in your class as one way.

`kwargs.get(pk name)`

You could change post to:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You then can't just assign `obj.post_comment = kwargs.get(pk)` you have to actually get the object.

`Post.objects.get(pk = pk)`

You might want to also consider renaming `fieldname_comment` to just `fieldname` for your models fields. Seems a bit redundant to have `_comment` on every single field in the `Comment` model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how works class based views but I can tell you that self.pk does not exist in class based view,  you would try get form instance and get the I'd field from this instance...